# How to insert UTF-16 character with sed in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

I have a file coded as UTF-16 and I want to split each line into fields (at fixed positions) separated by commas.
I have tried the following:

**Option 1)**

```
sed -i 's/./&,/400;s/./&,/360;*<and so on for several positions in the line>* FILE
```

This seems to work, but when editing the file with vim, it is obvious that something is wrong, since the commas are displayed as a single character, but the other symbols are displayed as a two-byte character.

```
BEFORE: 2^@A^@U^@W^@2^@0^@1^@9^@0^@1^@0^@1^@0^@0^@0^@1^@0^@0^@

AFTER: 2^@,A^@U^@,W^@,2^@0^@1^@9^@0^@1^@0^@1^@,0^@0^@0^@1^@0^@0^@,
```

**Option 2)**

Then I tried to use ***sed*** again but, instead of "," I typed the UTF-16 code of the comma, that is 002c:

```
sed -i "s/./&\U002c/400...
```

or even

```
s/./&$(echo -ne '\u002c')/400...
```

None of these options worked, the results are exactly the same as in Option1.

Comment: Please notice that ^@ are not two characters or bytes, but how vi represents the extra byte of UTF-16 for each character. As you can see, the comma character is represented by vi just as a single character ","

Comment: Can't you just convert the thing to UTF-8 (with, say, `iconv`), perform your modifications, and convert it back to UTF-16 when you're done? Better yet, tell vim the correct encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the insertion of a new character with sed.

I noticed that the file is UTF-16LE (I was assuming it was UTF-16BE). I converted it directly to ascii with

```
iconv -f UTF-16LE -t ASCII sourcefile >destinationfile
```

and after that I could handle the file as usual with sed, grep, awk, etc.